# Applications of Differential Calculus (KUMON Level O)

Tags: calculus

I don't understand what I need to do to solve this problem:

> Show that equation $$\frac{x^2 - 3}{x-1}=0$$ has $2$ real solutions in $[-2,2]$.

I've found the derivative which is:

$$f'(x) = \frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{(x-1)^2} > 0$$

The function is discontinuous at $x=1$.

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prove there are two roots in that interval, find two closed intervals$ [a,b] $where $f(a)f(b) <0$ and $f(x)$ is continuous. By Bolzano's Intermediate Value Theorem, there must be a root in each of those intervals

$[-2,-1] $ is one such interval since $f(-2)f(-1)= - \frac {1} {3} \cdot 1 \lt 0$

$[1.1,2]$ is another interval in which f has the same properties.

Since both intervals are subsets of$ [-2,2]$, both have a root (by IVT), and their intersection is null, f must have two distinct roots in$ [-2,2]$.

Edit: must have AT LEAST two distinct roots. There could be more (not in this particular case, of course)

Comment: Of course since the exercise is easy in this case you can just find the roots. This is for proving their existence in case finding them is not so easy

Answer (score 1):

Just solve 
$$\frac{x^2-3}{x-1}=0,$$
there is no need for calculus.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve $$\frac{x^2-3}{x-1}=0$$to solve it you can just multiply by $x-1$ both sides. $$x^2-3=0$$ hence the 2 solutions are $\pm\sqrt 3$. We know that there are no other solution because $\frac1{x-1}=0$ has no solutions and that $x^2-3$ is second degree thus it has at most $2$ roots

Answer (score -1):

$Y’$ is alway greater than $0$ in the domain thus the function is always increasing in the domain at approaching $1$ from the negative side it is equal to infinity for the positive side it is equal to negative infinity and $f(-2)$ is smaller then $0$ so that is one real solution because the function is increasing  so it goes from some thing negative to infinity it will pass by $0$ and from negative infinity to posit if something it will go by $0$ too. thus there is two real solutions